# Is it possible to rotate a heatmap in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to generate a heatmap from data that represents true x,y locations.

The problem is that if I group my data by x location the count of y values is not consistent enough for gnuplot to plot the data.  For example I have something like this

```
for x 2.13 I have 2240 y values
for x 4.77 I have 128 y values
for x 12.33 I have 2368 y values
```

gnuplot gives a warning (Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N  = 151552 K = 2240)

But if I group my data by y location, each y value has exactly 512 x values, so I end up with a perfect matrix.

But now in the displayed plot, the x axis is actually the y location values and vise-versa. This makes it very hard to visualize the data based on true x,y locations.

There seems to be ways to flip and rotate the image if you provide a binary file, but I am just providing a text file.  Is there a way to rotate/flip the image so that the x location is on the x axis and the y location is on the y axis?

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the command you used, but here is an example of plotting from a square matrix twice, once with data interpreted in the order  and once with the same data interpreted in the order .  The difference is in the order of columns in the `using` specifier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that if I swap the x y locations gnuplot would not plot the data at all.  My problem is that the data is not perfectly gridded so I should not even be trying to use image.  I changed to using pm3d and dgrid3d and I am able to get plots with the correct orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having above was due to my data not really being a perfect matrix.  I swapped from using "image" to pmd3 along with "dgrid3d" which allows for plotting "scattered" data, and I was able to plot my data without swapping x and y coordinates.